# Writing to different files according to the loop variable

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, io

Consider the following MWE.

```
f_500 = open('halo_classificatio_500_with_surface_pressure_term.txt', 'a')
f_200 = open('halo_classificatio_200_with_surface_pressure_term.txt', 'a')
f_178 = open('halo_classificatio_178_with_surface_pressure_term.txt', 'a')
f_100 = open('halo_classificatio_100_with_surface_pressure_term.txt', 'a')

over_density = [500,200,178,100]
for jj in over_density:
    tm_msun = 2
    cm_msun = 2
    vr_mpc = 2
    file('f_'+str(jj)).write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (tm_msun, cm_msun, vr_mpc))
```

I am getting the following error

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'f_500'

I would like to write to file object f_500 when '*jj*' is 500 and so on. What could be the correct way of doing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining 4 variables whose values are `file` type objects on lines 1-4. However, you're not using these variables in your `for` loop. Instead, in your loop, you're creating more `file` type objects. (The built-in [`file()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) function constructs a `file` type object with the given name.)

If you really want to open all the files beforehand, you should use a dictionary. The filenames can be constructed using a loop, too:

```
over_density = [500, 200, 178, 100]
filename_pattern = 'halo_classificatio_%d_with_surface_pressure_term.txt'
files = {}
for d in over_density:
    files[d] = open(filename_pattern % d, 'a')
```

After that, you can do your `for jj` loop and access the appropriate file handle with `files[jj]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I exactly looking.

Answer (score 2):

Access file variable as key in dict returned by  [globals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) or [locals()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals), depends on context:

```
locals()['f_'+str(jj)].write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (tm_msun, cm_msun, vr_mpc))
globals()['f_'+str(jj)].write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (tm_msun, cm_msun, vr_mpc))
```

Good Luck ! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need be doing in the last statement :

```
exec('''f_%s.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (tm_msun, cm_msun, vr_mpc))''' % (str(jj)) )
```

Comment: Not agree with using  exec ... http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/

Comment: That's your choice, I have been using exec for quite a lot of use cases never encountered any problem.